# Get product attribute value in GraphQL api

Tags: magento2, api, graphql

I'm having a problem with the GraphQL API for Magento 2. I cannot retrieve the attribute value of multiselect or dropdown attributes when I retrieve my products.

In this example my attribute "material" returns an integer of the value ID instead of the textual value. I'm currently using the endpoint https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/reference/custom-attribute-metadata.html to retrieve all the option values, but this is not very efficient.

```
{
  products(
    search: "Chair"
    pageSize: 10
  )
  {
    total_count
    items {
      name
      sku
      material
      price {
        regularPrice {
          amount {
            value
            currency
          }
        }
      }
    }
    page_info {
      page_size
      current_page
    }
  }
}
```

returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "products": {
      "total_count": 48,
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "Brown Chair",
          "sku": "4203894",
          "material": 209,
          "price": {
            "regularPrice": {
              "amount": {
                "value": 89,
                "currency": "EUR"
              }
            }
          }
        },
    .......
```

Is there a way to get the textual value of the "material" attribute ("Leather") in this call?

Comment: [Try this](https://github.com/theshreyas/magento-2-quickies/tree/main/GraphQl/DynamicAttributesGraphql)

Answer (score 1):

From Native GraqpQl we cannot get the expected result.But we can write a custom module with the graphql and achieve it.What my suggestion is get the product detail by sku using `_productRepository->get($sku);`. This will return the entire product details.So you can get the attribute data by using `$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();`
Here is my data provider file

```
/**
 * @params string $sku
 * this function return all the product data by product sku
 **/
public function getProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
}
/**
 * @params int $id
 * this function return all the word of the day by id
 **/
public function getAttributesBySku( $sku ){
    $_product = $this->getProductBySku($sku);
    $attributes = $_product->getAttributes();// All Product Attributes

    $attributes_data = [];
    $x=0;
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if($attribute->getIsUserDefined()){ // Removed the system product attribute by checking the current attribute is user created
            $attributeLabel = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel();
            $attributeValue = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

            if($attribute->getAttributeCode()=="language"){
                $attributeLabelAndValue = $attributeLabel." - ".$attributeValue;
                $attributes_data[$x]['atr_data'] = $attributeLabelAndValue;
            }
        }
        $x++;
    }
    return $attributes_data;
}
```

this code will return the need

```
$attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); this will return the label and 
$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); this will return the value.
```

To check the entire graphQl query and resolver file kindly view [How to get product attribute value, label using GraphQl in Magento 2.3?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-get-product-attribute-value-label-using-graphql-in-magento-2-3/)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: please help me on this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/307590/28348