# GraphQl get Product collection

Tags: magento2, rest-api, graphql

I have created Rest API for getting product collection for learning purpose , I wanted to convert it in GraphQl Api.
My question is below code valid for GraphQl or there is something else? My rest APi code:

```
<?php
namespace Kanika\Myapi\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException; 
class Productapi implements \Kanika\Myapi\Api\ProductapiInterface
{

     protected $_productCollection;
     public function __construct(           
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $_productCollection
        ) {        

            $this->_productCollection = $_productCollection;           
        }
     public function getlist($category_ids,$is_featured,$special_price,$brands,$product_type,$page=1,$pagesize=10){
        $collection = $this->_productCollection->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        if(!empty($category_ids)){
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' =>[$category_ids]]);
        }
        if($is_featured==1){
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_featuredproduct', array('eq' => 1));
        }
        if($special_price==1){
            $todayDate = date('m/d/y');
            $tomorrow = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d')+1, date('y'));
            $tomorrowDate = date('m/d/y', $tomorrow);

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                        'special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $tomorrowDate),
                        1 => array('is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                        ), 'left'
                    );
        }    
        if($product_type=='bundle'){ // bundle | simple | configruable
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','bundle');
        }
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $data=[];
        $collection->setPageSize($pagesize)->setCurPage($page)->load();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
           $data[] = [
                'id'=>$product->getId(),
                'sku'=>$product->getSku(),
                'name'=>$product->getName(),
                'brand'=>$product->getBrand(),
                'price'=>$product->getPrice(),
                'special_price'=>$product->getSpecialPrice(),
                'product_type'=>$product->getTypeId()
           ];
        }
        $pagination=[
            'current_page'=>$page,
            'last_page'=>$collection->getLastPageNumber(),
            #'total_product'=>$collection->count()
        ];
        return [
            'items'=>$data,
            'pagination'=>$pagination
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: @for GrpahQl you want resolver and data-provider files to get the result.You can use the same code to data-provider file to get the result. Simply we are doing the operation of the code here in data-provider file. you can read more articles about grpahql here http://www.mujahidh.com/

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/graphql/develop/resolvers.html


go through this doc 

Only Resolvers

Answer (score 0):

You have to create schema.graphqls and resolver class to implement this graphql and some changes too. create a resolver class with graphql exception handling & some part of above code would definitely work.